# How can I shrink the size of conn_log table

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL instance, `conn_log` table contains thousands of billion connections records. As a result, it consume too much storage size. Is there a way to cut down the size or disable connection logs?

```
mysql> select count(*) from conn_log;
+------------+
| count(*)   |
+------------+
| 4215139229 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: do you mean [this](http://serverfault.com/a/490022) where you are saving it to a table ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. The cause why test.conn_log table had thousands of billion records is I set the `init_connect` variable as follows.

```
insert into test.conn_log values(connection_id(),now(),@user,@cur_user,'');
```

So when a connection is established, a record will be insert into test.conn_log table.